# Current AngularJS module organization requires circular module references

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a SPA that uses ngTable and ui-bootstrap.  The page references a top-level controller defined in a top-level module, and several nested controllers that are defined in other modules.  There are several clear references from the nested controllers to services or scope variables in the top-level controller, so the nested modules have references to the top-level module. However, in order for this to run without error, I have to reference all of the nested modules from the top-level module.

If I don't reference the nested modules from the top-level module, I get an error like this:

```
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'DataSourcesCtrl' is not a function, got undefined
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.4/ng/areq?p0=DataSourcesCtrl&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
minErr/<@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.4/angular.js:78
assertArg@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.4/angular.js:1358
assertArgFn@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.4/angular.js:1369
@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.4/angular.js:6682
applyDirectivesToNode/nodeLinkFn/<@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.4/angular.js:6098
forEach@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.4/angular.js:307
nodeLinkFn@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.4/angular.js:6085
compositeLinkFn@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.4/angular.js:5551
publicLinkFn@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.4/angular.js:5459
.link@http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/EBVfG1gWYv7xf8sa5v8a/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.js:2822
nodeLinkFn@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.4/angular.js:6140
compositeLinkFn@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.4/angular.js:5548
publicLinkFn@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.4/angular.js:5459
boundTranscludeFn@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.4/angular.js:5570
controllersBoundTransclude@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.4/angular.js:6160
ngRepeatAction@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.4/angular.js:18996
$watchCollectionAction@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.4/angular.js:11449
Scope.prototype.$digest@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.4/angular.js:11552
Scope.prototype.$apply@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.4/angular.js:11803
bootstrap/doBootstrap/<@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.4/angular.js:1297
invoke@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.4/angular.js:3644
bootstrap/doBootstrap@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.4/angular.js:1296
bootstrap@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.4/angular.js:1309
angularInit@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.4/angular.js:1258
@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.4/angular.js:20306
n.Callbacks/j@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js:2
n.Callbacks/k.fireWith@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js:2
.ready@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js:2
K@http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js:2
```

---

```
<div class="tab-pane ng-scope" ng-repeat="tab in tabs" ng-class="{active: tab.active}" tab-content-transclude="tab">
```

As you can see in my [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/EBVfG1gWYv7xf8sa5v8a) that demonstrates this, the "DataSourcesCtrl" is a controller defined in 'DataSourcesModule' in "dataSourcesMod.js".  If you comment out the line near the top of "diagapp.js", it will run without error.

This is what the top of "diagapp.js" looks like:

```
var diagapp = angular.module("DiagApp", ['ui.bootstrap'
//                 , 'DataSourcesModule' // Comment out this line to demonstrate problem
                                     ]);
```

I guess I can understand now why I have to load all of the modules in the top-level module, because otherwise there's no other way for those modules to be loaded.  However, when I do that, I end up with circular module references, which seems wrong.  Nothing directly inside the top-level module references anything in the nested modules.

It seems like I need to adjust my module organization.  What is the best way to deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the obvious and reasonable advice would be to have a top-level module that loads all the other required modules for the page, along with any configuration settings for that module, but which has nothing directly needed by any of the other modules.

In this example, that would mean separating out some pieces of the top-level "DiagApp" module into a "DiagMod" module.  This would include any components that the other modules need to use.  If the top-level module doesn't need any configuration settings, then the top-level module would just have the single line specifying all the modules used on the page, including the new "DiagMod" module.